# Postgres multiple schemas comparison in objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema, postgresql-9.5

Hi I have none trivial job, I have DB which contains 200 schemes one of them I would call the "STANDARD" schema, I need to compare all of the schemas on this DB against the 'standard'.

Using Postgres (PGAdmin) comparison functionality doesn't work for me as , it cannot properly work with schema names.
example:

`select * from standard.table_A` vs `select * from some_schema.table_A`

will be non-match as in this situation schema names in the query are different and comparison tool think it is the difference.  I am looking for some tool that will be able to compare schemas with different names vs one schema, or just ignore schema names in this case.

Comment: This will not get an answer until you explain what is you are comparing?: 1) Schema names 2) Schema contents 3) Schema objects contents e.g. table data, function definitions, etc. You cannot ignore schema names as they are literally the namespace that allows for like named objects to exist in a single database and so are the only way to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: this will rely heavy on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/information-schema.html Tables columns there you get the information to comapre

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am trying to compare objects in schemas, I have one schema which is gold standard and I need to know all differences in objects. all schemas in one db

Comment: Then you are going to spend time in the [System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that is the problem I don't want, I am looking for some solution which may alredy exists see no reason to re-inventing a bicycle if it is already exists

Comment: I am trying to understand this `select * from standard.table_A vs select * from some_schema.table_A`? Do you mean if this is in a function or a view definition it will be seen as different? If that is the case  then I don't know of a tool that would ignore that.